# How to get data from next page in Protractor test?

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor, ui-automation

I'm automating test of booking a flight. On the homepage I enter credentials for a flight, click Submit button and browser goes to the page with search result.

```
    const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

describe('Delta airlines booking sample', function () {

    const toAirportName = element(by.id('toAirportName'));
    const toAirportNameSearchInput = element(by.id('search_input'));
    const berlinCityAirport = element(by.css('li.airport-list:nth-child(1)'));
    const tripTypeSelector = element(by.id('selectTripType-val'));
    const tripTypeOneWay = element(by.id('ui-list-selectTripType1'));
    const departmentDateLabel = element(by.id('calDepartLabelCont'));
    const departureDate = element(by.xpath("//a[@aria-label='5 November 2020, Thursday']"))
    const departureDatePickerDone = element(by.xpath("//button[@aria-label='done']"));
    const buttonBookSubmit = element(by.id('btn-book-submit'));
    const errorMessage = element(by.id('advance-search-global-err-msg'));

    beforeEach(function () {
        browser.get('https://www.delta.com/');
        browser.manage().window().maximize();
    });


    it('should have to airport destination field clickable', () => {
        toAirportName.click();
        toAirportNameSearchInput.sendKeys('Berlin \n');
        berlinCityAirport.getText().then(text => {
            text.includes('BER') ? berlinCityAirport.click() : console.log('Wrong search result');
        });
        tripTypeSelector.click();
        tripTypeOneWay.click();
        departmentDateLabel.click();
        departureDate.click();
        departureDatePickerDone.click();
        buttonBookSubmit.click();
        browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(errorMessage), 10000);
        expect(errorMessage.getText()).toEqual("Uh-oh! We're sorry, but no results were found for your search.We have adjusted our flight schedules and some of our flights only operate seasonally or on select days of the week.Try changing your cities or dates for additional results.#101763R");
    }); 
});
```

As you see - I'm not using any pageobjects. I'm trying to get error code from searchresult page as it is a part of homepage (quite naive, right?). As new page's URL contains `?cacheKeySuffix=....` and that's why it will be changed every time the test is running.

How can I get data from search result page?

How

Comment: What data are you trying to get? Why did you mention the url? Is that important to this test? Is the error message actually displayed? You have to give us some more details. At least for me, it's unclear what is going wrong here. Is the test failing?

Answer (score 1):

So if i understand this correctly, you are trying to check if the error message shows up properly but you need to know that theres no flights to Berlin.

End to end tests have to run reliably. If you dont have access to that data (programatically) i dont think its a good idea to test it. You should already know that theres no flights to Berlin before your test even starts.